# how to wrap a library without build files in meteor package

Tags: meteor, package

I try to wrap a javascript library with a meteor package.

When i fork the library it has no built javascript file inside the repository. Normally someone would run **grunt dist** to build the **dist/library.js** file.

Meteor Package description:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.addFiles([
    'dist/library.js', 
  ])
})M
```

this can't work because the file does not exist yet.

How can i create a package from that library? is coping the library.js file the only way?

Comment: Can you share the link to the code repository for this package?

Comment: https://github.com/quilljs/quill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this, you're going to have to require Grunt, run Grunt through the JavaScript API (*not* the CLI) to compile `dist/library.js`, and then require it.

It would be *much* easier to just compile it outside of Meteor and place it in the folder, but if you want to do things The Right Way™ that's how you'd do it. Let me know if you have any implementation-specific questions!

Comment: I guess i have to use Npm.depend(grunt, '1.2.3.4') inside package.js but where do i require and run it?